# C++ convert string literal to multi-character literal at compile time

Tags: c++, string, character, metaprogramming, string-literals

Basically, if I have this string:

```
"abcd"
```

I want to end up with the equivalent of:

```
'abcd'
```

*at compile time*. I have tried using macros, preprocessor magic, and Microsoft's charize operator (`#@`), but none of them work correctly. The end result should allow me to do something like this:

```
template <long N> struct some_type {};
long whatever = STR_TO_MULTI_CHAR_LITERAL("abcd");
some_type<whatever> xyz;
```

Comment: *"Microsoft's charize operator"* So you're using the MSVC compiler? Which version? VS2015 / MSVC 19 supports constexpr functions..

Comment: @dyp `clang -fms-extensions`, though the result should work under MSVC *without* constexpr.

Comment: It might be possible to explode the string into a sequence of characters ([via macros](http://web.archive.org/web/20130930081424/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2012/10/using-strings-in-c-template-metaprograms/)) and then rebuild a number from that sequence of characters.

Comment: Is it possible in your case to add a definition of a global/static local variable that contains the string? Something like `const char str[] = "abcd";` -- this could be used to pass the string to a metafunction; passing a string literal directly is not allowed.

Comment: @dyp But then can I index it?

Comment: Hmmm not at compile time it seems. I'm not entirely sure why, though. Maybe because in general, you could also supply a string that has not been initialized yet (`extern char const arr[4];` etc.) or that is dynamically initialized (`char arr[4];`). Anyway, the solution I was looking for is far too general in this case. A simple macro as in ecatmur's solution is probably more appropriate here.

Comment: Ah, I just forgot about the restrictions of `const` objects inside constant expressions: they need to have integral or enumeration type. The restrictions on `constexpr` objects are far less strict.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that we can forget about big/little endian for now, you could use a  `constexpr` `union` like

```
union dirty_hack {
    long l;
    char[4] chars;
};
```

If we need to consider endian, it becomes more complex. Also size of `long` could be 8, not 4.

Another thought, if `long` is 32bit, `char32_t char4b = U'\UAABBFFFF'` is supported in C++11. But then you need figure out the map from `A` to `45` (hex value of `A`). Then cast `char4b` to `long`.

Comment: Type punning at compile time will most likely not work. In Standardese, type punning through a union is forbidden in C++, and `reinterpret_cast` is forbidden inside constant expressions as well. (There's a more fundamental reason why type punning is forbidden at compile time, but I keep forgetting it..) See http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1188

Comment: @dyp, you are right, it may not be feasible in C++. maybe just use C for that part.

Answer (score 1):

If you can compile *in C++11 mode* (or above), then you're allowed to index into string literals at constant-expression time:

```
#define STR_TO_MULTI_CHAR_LITERAL(s)                 \
    (sizeof(s) == 5                                  \
        ? s[0] << 24 | s[1] << 16 | s[2] << 8 | s[3] \
        : throw "wrong length")
some_type<STR_TO_MULTI_CHAR_LITERAL("abcd")> xyz;
```

That said, if you're allowed to use C++11 mode you should be able to use `constexpr` as well:

```
constexpr std::int32_t strToMultiCharLiteral(char const (&s)[5]) {
    return s[0] << 24 | s[1] << 16 | s[2] << 8 | s[3];
}
some_type<strToMultiCharLiteral("abcd")> xyz;
```

You can even write a user-defined string literal:

```
constexpr std::int32_t operator""_multiCharLiteral(char const *s, std::size_t len)
{
  return len == 4 ? s[0] << 24 | s[1] << 16 | s[2] << 8 | s[3]
    : throw "wrong length";
}
some_type<"abcd"_multiCharLiteral> xyz;
```

Comment: Nice ideas, but the OP said (in the comments) this must run under MSVC w/o `constexpr`. Unfortunately, VS2013 rejects `"abcd"[0]` as a constant expression :(